# Get multiple values in one column from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

`A` table:

```
id_a | description
-------------------
  1  |      X   
  2  |      Y        
  3  |      Z 
  4  |      H
```

`B` table:

```
id_b | description
-------------------
  1  |      J   
  2  |      K        
  3  |      W
```

`C` table:

```
id_c | idex_a | idex_b | quantity
----------------------------------
  1  |    1   |   1    |   10 
  2  |    1   |   2    |   32 
  3  |    2   |   3    |   41 
  4  |    1   |   3    |   10 
  5  |    3   |   2    |   24 
  6  |    3   |   3    |   26
```

How can I obtain this result?

```
A.id_a | A.description | All B.description, B.quantity IN C WHITH A.id_a = C.idex_a
   1   |       X       | J[10], K[32], W[10]
   2   |       Y       | W[41]
   3   |       Z       | K[24], W[26]
   4   |       H       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
select a.id_a
      , a.description
      , coalesce( group_concat(distinct concat(b.description, '[', c.quantity, ']') order by b.id_b separator ', ')
                , '') 
from a
left join c on a.id_a = c.idex_a
left join b on b.id_b = c.idex_b
group by a.id_a
       , a.description
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d870b/4)